# Playframework 2.0.3 - Reloading database driver after every compilation

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm working with Play 2.0.3, configured to work with MySQL. Everything works fine but the problem is very simple : 
After EVERY change in one of the views(even simple HTML element) it takes huge time to reload the app and test it. I can see in the output that the mysql connection is rebuilt. 
This is the output :

```
--- (RELOAD) ---

[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?useUni
code=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci
[info] play - Application started (Dev)
```

Keep in mind this is a very simple app. Just started to build it. 
It takes like 5-10 seconds to test every simple HTML/view change.

Am I missing something here ? **I found that complication time is an issue on Play 2.0**, but how can I at least avoid reloading the database connection ?

Thanks,
David.

Comment: Has this problem still not been resolved with the Play Framework? Its taking me 54 seconds on each page refresh after updating a LESS file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt if it's configurable somehow, there are some tips, which will help you and I think it's best to mix all of them:

1. Run your app for development with: `play ~run` - it will cause recompiling in the background, right after file changes. It won't shorten the recompilation time, but at least it will be less annoying.
2. Try to write more at once :) when you're browsing every small change and think '*ah, this detail yet... ah this detail yet...*' the time needed for recompilation can be really terrible. Instead just check all details which you want to fix and insert the changes at once. If you'll spend minute or two for fixing layout's details then waiting 5 seconds will not be such terrible thing.
3. Use browser's inspection tool for debugging output HTML - you can see where the bugs lays and test small code modifications without inserting them into the view.
4. If you have really complicated layout with lot of JS, CSS etc. save an output rendered with Play as a static files and first make it working as you want. When you'll finish then you'll move changes in the static HTML to the view. Testing changes in static files will be just much faster as it doesn't require to recompile'em each time.
5. Use a git (even if as a only local repository). With combination of git and IDE supporting it you'll just see where you've made a changes and what do you need to move from static test-files to the final version of the views or assets.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer ! very useful tips. BTW - I already use ~run but the rest of the tips, especially the static files usage are very good. Already started to implement them. Thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug.  I'd recommend creating a small reproducible test case and reporting it at the bug tracker:
https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/overview